# Python with Seleneium Webdriver .text dont display

Tags: python, selenium

I wrote the code to get items from the site.
I find them on the page but I can not display them with the help of .text
Why is this code not working properly? Please help me.

```
from selenium import  webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.akademia-playdoh.pl/akademiawyobrazni,konkurs,31.html')

driver.execute_script("$('.item-content').css('display', 'block');")
ListItem = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(lambda browse: driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".item-content p"))

print('Zebrane dane')
id=1
for item in ListItem:
    print("ID: " + str(id) + " " + item.text)
    id = id + 1

driver.close()
```

Please help me.

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: I'm not getting a mistake.
I get empty strings.

Comment: There are 1704 items on the site that I want to find and all I get as empty strings.

Comment: item .get_attribute('innerHTML') try with this

Comment: It's works! Thanks you. :)

Comment: Please accept my answer so other can get help from it .. click on check sign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below line of code :-

```
item.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```